Will my device mini pc work with Ubuntu 20.04
I have such a question, I ordered myself a mini PC for a home server, a mini PC from GenMachine with a Rayzen 5 5600U processor, 16 DRR4, 1 tb ssd nvme, is it possible to install Ubuntu 20-04-22.04 LTS on this mini PC?

Just install Ubuntu. It should work.

By the way, the latest LTS for Ubuntu is 24.04 (supported until 2029). Support for 20.04 and 22.04 will end at 2025 and 2027, respectively

This question is similar to: Will my device work with Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You see, I ordered a mini PC on Aliexpress and the seller told me that installation on Ubuntu is impossible, although this is strange because the mini PC meets the minimum/recommended specifications of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I want to use the mini PC as a home server where my sites will work, so I decided to ask people if this mini PC is compatible with Ubuntu LTS Linux, because it seems to me that the seller gave me a little bit of wrong information about the impossibility of installing this operating system on a mini PC, I use a translator

The mini pc comes with windows 11 out of the box, I don't think that Ubuntu LTS 20.04 can't be installed on this mini pc that supports windows 11

Given we don't know about the mini PC, and you don't yet have access to it, we really cannot answer the question. The only way to know if it works is to try installing Ubuntu, and in most cases, Ubuntu works out of the box.
